# Find only those galleries with images

Tags: wp-query, images, gallery

Is there a way in WordPress to use `WP_Query` and retrieve posts/galleries that have more than 0 metavalues with the key `_gallery_image_ids`?

Essentially I don't want to display galleries that have no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a relatively simple `meta_query` would do it.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_gallery_image_ids',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters